# Window Fetch Response can't be converted to JSON when URL object passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, undici

According to [the documentation of the Fetch method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) , it accepts a:

> resource
>
> This defines the resource that you wish to fetch. This can either be:
>
> A string or any other object with a stringifier — including a URL object — that provides the URL of the resource you want to fetch.
>
> A Request object.

But when I construct a `URL` the response body is `stream: undefined`:

```js
  const url = new URL(
    '/traffic',
    'https://some-base-domain.com'
  )
  const [err, res] = await to(fetch(url))

  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  const data = await res.json()
  return data
```

Response:

```json
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 404,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 5089772.463499999,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 5089772.463499999,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 431,
      decodedBodySize: 431,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: '',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(5) {
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'content-language' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

Comment: `the request fails` ... in what way? what does `to` do?

Comment: updated my question: There's a response but 1) its a 404 2) (naturally) it can't be converted to `json` using the `.json()` method. I pasted the Response object. `to` is an await wrapper, it helps you by hiding the `try/catch` block. https://github.com/scopsy/await-to-js

Comment: Since you know its a 404 it's not clear what your question is now. I can reproduce your code with `new URL('users', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')` for example and it works.

Comment: does your code work as expected when using a string url as the argument to `fetch()`? Is the issue here really to do with using a `URL` instance or something else?

Comment: I just experimented with the jsonplaceholder and I realized going back to my original code that it worked when I moved the `/` from the endpoint to the base... does it help for an answer?

Comment: `(naturally) it can't be converted to json using the .json() method` why not? the status has nothing to do with the response body

Comment: indeed, but in any case the response body was empty

Comment: beauty is always relevant to the observer! I find try/catch ugly.